# When casting a float or double to an int, is behaviour consistent across platforms?

Tags: c++

For example if I have:

```
float f = 3.3456;
float g = 3.676455;

int j = f;
int k = g;
```

When the f,g are cast to int, will the behaviour be the same across all platforms ? Will j,k always be 3 ?

For example, will k ever be 4 ?
Is the fractional part always truncated, or is it ever rounded ?

The reason this is slightly different from the question suggested as duplicate is that in this case the conversion is implicit. Please see the marked answer, as that directly contradicts the marked answer in the "duplicate question".

Comment: Terminology: That is assignment, not casting.

Comment: `sizeof int` isn't consistent across platforms, so the result of these assignments isn't either.

Comment: @user4581301 It is "implicitly" cast, during the assignment.

Comment: "cast" means an explicit conversion, there's no such thing as "implicit cast". You should say "converted" here

Comment: @user4581301 It is not assignment. It is initialization.

Comment: @EJP I guess what I'm trying to understand, is in the case of an implicit cast like this, is it always truncated ? or is a float ever rounded ?

Comment: @EJP the standard guarantees that `int` is large enough to hold the value `3`

Comment: @M.M Please see: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/ In my textbook it used the terminology "implicitly cast"

Comment: It is always truncated, never rounded. However your question as asked is ot confined to rounding vs truncation.

Comment: That site is a crappy site . But if you even read that page you will see that it does not describe implicit conversion as "casting"

Comment: @user4581301 Huh? A cast is an explicit conversion; `(int)3.3` is `3`

Comment: @user4581301 To convert binary representations is to do `float var = 3.125; int var2 = *(int*)(&var);` And that is generally a **bad idea**.

Comment: @InternetAussie well that code is a strict aliasing violation for starters

Comment: I don't really think this is a duplicate of the other;  the other asks whether floats of arbitrary values can be reliably converted to int, whereas this is specifically asking whether `(int)3.3` is allowed to be `4`.  There's a certain subset of float values which can be reliably converted.

Comment: @M.M Yeah I think so too. If you look at the answer I marked correct here, and the answer marked correct for the "duplicate" question, you will see that they contradict each other on whether the behaviour is the same across platforms. The other answer talks about rounding down, but this answer says that the conversion truncates... so I'm a bit confused here. I think the answer below makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [...] will the behaviour be the same across all platforms ?

Yes. Yes it will.

From [N4659](http://wg21.link/n4659) (my emphasis in **bold**):

> ### 7.10 Floating-integral conversions [conv.fpint]
>
> (1) A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. **The conversion truncates**; that is, **the fractional part is discarded.** **The behavior is undefined** if **the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type**.

Comment: I was under the impression that floating point numbers might round upwards? Like `(int)(3.0 * (1 / 3.0)) == 1`? Or does this actually truncates to 0

Comment: @PasserBy This is different again. The expression `(1 / 3.0)` is converted to `(1.0 / 3.0)` because of the *usual arithmetic conversions*  (these are defined in **§8. Expressions** in paragraph 11 (and described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic))). `(3.0 * (1.0 / 3.0))` would then be folded on and optimised as a constant expression by the compiler, resulting in `1.0`. *Now* the floating-integral conversions apply, converting `(int)1.0` to `1`.

Comment: Even if it were evaluated at compile-time, the value has to be the exact same as if the expression is evaluated at run-time, otherwise it doesn't make sense. Anyways, looking into it more, apparently the floating point error of `1 / 3.0` is positive, meaning `3.0 * (1 / 3.0)` will be `1.0`, exactly. [Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72d76ea03b98372c)

Comment: Looking further, it looks like arithmetic on floats are defined to be sane, and you don't really have to think much about it. [It just works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a9f573f2ebfd8e47)

Comment: @PasserBy Well, sane enough. There's going to be edge cases, but that's par for the course with programming and computers in general.